# Confinement energy of an electron in the nucleus

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Hullo,

I've got a relatively simple question in my homework and yet I can't seem to find a proper answer

I need to find the confinement energy of an electron in a Deuterium nucleus with the radius of $3\cdot10^{-15} m$ and am told that the resulting energy should be around a few MeV

I first tried to solve it myself by using the Heisenberg relation and the relativistic energy formula:

$\Delta p \approx \frac{\hbar}{2\Delta x} = 1.758\cdot10^{-16} \frac{kg\cdot m}{s}$

$E = \sqrt{E_0^2+p^2c^2} = 3.29\cdot 10^{11} \text{eV}$,

which obviously doesn't fit the desired range

I also found [this solution](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/uncer.html#c4) on Hyperphysics, which I don't quite get but I tried anyways and got

$\Delta p = 2.209\cdot 10^{-19}$

$E = 1.67\cdot 10^{11} \text{eV}$,

which doesn't bring me any closer to the desired answer

How should I go about solving this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure your homework is asking for confinement in the _nucleus_? From your link, it seems that it shouldn't even be possible.

Comment: @HantingZhang yes. A literal translation: "What energy must an electron have if it were a part of the nucleus?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using just $\Delta x \Delta p = \hbar/2$, and $E = \Delta P^{2}/2m_e$, I get 1,058 MeV.

If I use the mass of a proton, I get 0.5764 MeV.

Comment: Ah, I see. I believe I misunderstood the question, I think they meant that the _nucleon_ binding energy should be around a MeV, and the electron is no nucleon. Thank you for your help!